# Approach for implementing a timer in LWUIT APP

Tags: java-me, timer, lwuit

I am developing a quiz application using LWUIT where users can choose from different types of quizzes.

The user has the choice of taking a timed quiz or an untimed quiz. In a timed quiz, a count down timer will be displayed on top of the screen and the test will automatically be submitted when the timer ends.

How should I implement this in LWUIT? I am looking for an approach which will tackle this problem elegantly. Would really appreciate your comments and feedback.

Thanks ,

Nikhil.

Comment: Look at the J2ME `Javadoc` : there is a class `Timer`.

Comment: @pheromix thanks... i am using timer currently..was looking for something better with respect to LWUIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use an animation, just implement the `Animation` interface and use `Form.registerAnimated()`. Always return false from the animate() method and within it just update your UI based on the current time.

This is a superior approach to using the `java.util.Timer` API because the animation is invoked within the LWUIT EDT thread and not within a separate thread so you can just change the GUI without fear of a race condition.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this.. I had an intuition that LWUIT has something more to offer :)

Comment: Yes Shai Almog's approach is elegant ! He masters and knows LWUIT 100% ! He builts it so he masters it ! Isn't it ?